# How to create a responsive image that also scales up in Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using twitter bootstrap 3 and I am facing a problem to create a responsive image. I have used `img-responsive` class. But the image size is not scaling up. If I use `width:100%` instead of `max-width:100%` then it works perfectly.  Where is the problem? This is my code:

```
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 ">
        <div class="product">               
                <div class="product-img ">
                   <img class="img-responsive" src="img/show1.png" alt="" />
                </div>
             </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 85):

Bootstrap's responsive image class sets `max-width` to 100%. This limits its size, but does not force it to stretch to fill parent elements larger than the image itself. You'd have to use the `width` attribute to force upscaling.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive

Answer (score 18):

### Sure things!

`.img-responsive` is the right way to make images responsive with bootstrap 3
You can add some height rule for the picture you want to make responsive, because with responsibility, width changes along the height, fix it and there you are.

Answer (score 9):

I had to do a small trick to make the image bigger but keeping it responsive:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 368px) {
    img.smallResolution{
        min-height: 150px;
    }

}
```

P.S. The max width can be anything you like.

Comment: This does not cause an image to display wider than its native size.

Answer (score 7):

If setting a fixed width on the image is not an option, here's an alternative solution.

Having a parent div with display: table & table-layout: fixed.
Then setting the image to display: table-cell and max-width to 100%. That way the image will fit to the width of its parent.

Example:

```
<style>
    .wrapper { float: left; clear: left; display: table; table-layout: fixed; }
    img.img-responsive { display: table-cell; max-width: 100%; }
</style>
<div class="wrapper col-md-3">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5y62c4af/

Answer (score 5):

Try the following in your CSS stylesheet:

```
.img-responsive{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to do so:

1) In your index.html

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
  <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <div class="ratio" style="background-image:url('../Images/img1.jpg')"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

2) In your style.css

```
.ratio {
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50%; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can put the .col class on the image will do the trick - however this gives it extra padding along with any other attributes associated with the class such as float left, however these can be cancelled by say for example a no padding class as an addition.

Answer (score -2):

I guess image is than corrupted.
Example: image size is 195px X 146px.

It will work inside lower resolutions like tablets. When you have 1280 X 800 resolution it will force larger as there is also width 100 %. Maybe CSS inside media query like icons fonts is the best solution.