# Displaying Responsive Images using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap which has a gallery view and on a large screen it shows 3 columns and 2 rows on a tablet and then a single column on a phone.

The images I use for the large screen are relatively of correct size but when we move it towards the phone the image is smaller in width compared to the size of the window.

Which is the best way to handle this issue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The aspect ratio looks right. 
Do you have something constraining the height of the image?

try forcing the the width of the image to fill the parent i.e. class=col-xs-12

You could checkout this reference. The asker is having a simular issue. Maybe one of their answers will help you.

[How to create a responsive image that also scales up in Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903183/how-to-responsive-image-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 1):

To ensure it fits within the entire space of the column once the grid has 'collapsed', you can add `width: 100%;` to allow the image to take up the full width of the column.

#### Basic Example:

```html
<style type="text/css">
    .imagecolumn img {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 imagecolumn">
       <img src="../Landscape.jpg" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 imagecolumn">
       <img src="../Mountain-Landscape-Wallpaper.jpg" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 imagecolumn">
       <img src=../Snake-River-Idaho.jpg" />
   </div>
</div>
```

**Demo Fiddle**: **http://jsfiddle.net/ebJbZ/**

Although, It seems your structure has `<div>`'s within each inner column - it should have a grid structure alike:

```html
<div class="row">
    <!-- Outer Column -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            
            <!-- Inner Full-width Column -->
            <div class="col-md-12 imagecolumn">
                <img src="../Landscape.jpg" />
                Picture One
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Outer Column -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">

            <!-- Inner Full-width Column -->
            <div class="col-md-12 imagecolumn">
                <img src="../Mountain-Landscape-Wallpaper.jpg" />
                Picture Two
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Outer Column -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">

            <!-- Inner Full-width Column -->
            <div class="col-md-12 imagecolumn">
                <img src=../Snake-River-Idaho.jpg" />
                Picture Three
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is so the image will *match* the full-width *inner column*, as:

> `col-md-12` is equal too 100%;

**Demo Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/mXmf9/

Comment: should i add it to the div or the image itself?

Comment: Now that'll depend on the grid structure of your columns, if the `<div />`s within the columns should be `col-xs-12` to ensure it matches the full width of the inner column, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @HarshaMV Edited, but an answer to your question in short, with a *full width*'ed inner-column - the image should match the size anyway.