# How to keep images fixed but also responsive so they don't overlap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I trying to achieve like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqSlL.jpg).

Problem is that this is responsive So individual images like iphone, logo , headphone stack below each other in smaller screen.

I want there positions of be fixed in container. I don't want images to stacked below each other.
How to position images like this using bootstrap?
I want website to be responsive but also position of images remain exact.

Help will be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url('background.png'); width: 100%; height: 100%;position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; overflow: hidden; background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">

                <div id="iphone" class="col-xs-4">
                </div>
                <div id="camera" class="col-xs-4">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">

                nothing
                </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">

                <div id="headphones" class="col-xs-4">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">

                <div id="notebook" class="col-xs-4">
                </div>
                <div id="glasses" class="col-xs-4">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">

                <div id="logo" class="col-xs-4">
                </div>
                </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">

                <div id="gopro" class="col-xs-4">
                </div>
                <div id="controller" class="col-xs-4">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="cookie" class="col-xs-4">
                </div>
                <div id="tea" class="col-xs-4">
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="macbook" class="col-xs-4">
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="pen" class="col-xs-4">
                </div>
                <div id="harddisk" class="col-xs-4">
                </div>
                <div id="iwatch" class="col-xs-4">
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/********************iphone*******************************/
#iphone
{
    position: relative;
    top:-110px;
    left:-140px; 
    background-image: url('../images/New Folder/iPhone.-3.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
    height: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 196px;
    padding-top: 102.04%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) */
                /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #iphone { height: auto;
    max-width:50%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #iphone {height: auto;
    max-width:60%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    #iphone { height: auto;
    max-width:100%; }
}
/********************headphones***************************/
#headphones
{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    top:-30px;
    right:-130px; 
    background-image: url('../images/New Folder/headphones-2.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
    height: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 450px;
    padding-top: 102.04%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) */
                /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #headphones { height: auto;
    max-width:50%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #headphones {height: auto;
    max-width:60%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    #headphones { height: auto;
    max-width:100%; }
}
/******************camera***********************/
#camera
{
    position: relative;

    top:110px;
    left:-300px;
    background-image: url('../images/New Folder/camera-2.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
    height: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
    width: 160px;
    height: 182px;
    padding-top: 102.04%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) */
                /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #camera { height: auto;
    max-width:50%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #camera {height: auto;
    max-width:60%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    #camera { height: auto;
    max-width:100%; }
}
/***********notebook*******************/
#notebook
{
    position: relative;

    top:-190px;
    left:-130px; 
    background-image: url('../images/New Folder/moleskine-1.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
    height: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 275px;
    padding-top: 109.47%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) */
                /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #notebook { height: auto;
    max-width:50%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #notebook {height: auto;
    max-width:60%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    #notebook { height: auto;
    max-width:100%; }
}
/****************glasses******************/
#glasses
{
    position: absolute;

    top:-110px;
    left:0px; 
    background-image: url('../images/New Folder/glasses-1.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
    height: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 156px;
    padding-top: 192.36%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) */
                /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
    z-index: 1000;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #glasses { height: auto;
    max-width:50%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #glasses {height: auto;
    max-width:60%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    #glasses { height: auto;
    max-width:100%; }
}
/**************logo************************/
#logo
{
    position: relative;

    top:-300px;
    left:0px; 
    background-image: url('../images/New Folder/logo-transparent.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
    height: auto;
    max-width:200%;
    display:block;
    width: 3800px;
    height: 1800px;
    padding-top: 225.07%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) */
                /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
    z-index: 1000;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #logo { height: auto;
    max-width:50%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #logo {height: auto;
    max-width:60%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    #logo { height: auto;
    max-width:100%; }
}
/******************gopro*****************/
#gopro
{
    position: relative;

    top:-100px;
    left:0px;  
    background-image: url('../images/New Folder/GoPro-1.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
    height: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 121px;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 95.02%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) */
                /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
    z-index: 1000;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #gopro { height: auto;
    max-width:50%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #gopro {height: auto;
    max-width:60%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    #gopro { height: auto;
    max-width:100%; }
}
/********************controller****************/
#controller
{
    position: relative;

    top:-100px;
    left:240px; 
    background-image: url('../images/New Folder/console-2.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
    height: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 95px;
    padding-top: 68.9%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) */
                /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
    z-index: 1000;
    float: left;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #controller { height: auto;
    max-width:50%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #controller {height: auto;
    max-width:60%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    #controller { height: auto;
    max-width:100%; }
}
/**************tea****************/
#tea
{
    position: absolute;

    top:-870px;
    left:100px; 
    background-image: url('../images/New Folder/tea-1.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
    height: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
    width: 180px;
    height: 160px;
    padding-top: 95.9%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) */
                /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
    z-index: 1000;
    float: right;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #tea { height: auto;
    max-width:50%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #tea {height: auto;
    max-width:60%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    #tea { height: auto;
    max-width:100%; }
}
/****************cookie****************/
#cookie
{
    position: absolute;

    top:-870px;
    left:0px;  
    background-image: url('../images/New Folder/cookies-2.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
    height: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
    width: 90px;
    height: 82px;
    padding-top: 95.9%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) */
                /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
    z-index: 1000;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #cookie { height: auto;
    max-width:50%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #cookie {height: auto;
    max-width:60%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    #cookie { height: auto;
    max-width:100%; }
}
/****************macbook****************/
#macbook
{
    position: relative;

    top:-1000px;
    left:0px; 
    background-image: url('../images/New Folder/MacBook-1.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
    height: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
    width: 550px;
    height: 447px;
    padding-top: 123.04%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) */
                /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
    z-index: 1000;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #macbook { height: auto;
    max-width:50%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #macbook {height: auto;
    max-width:60%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    #macbook { height: auto;
    max-width:100%; }
}
/**************************harddisk*****************/
#harddisk
{
    position: absolute;

   top:-1000px;
    left:250px; 
    background-image: url('../images/New Folder/hard-disk-1.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
    height: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 325px;
    padding-top: 92.302%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) */
                /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
    z-index: 1000;
    float: right;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #harddisk { height: auto;
    max-width:50%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #harddisk {height: auto;
    max-width:60%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    #harddisk { height: auto;
    max-width:100%; }
}
/********************iwatch*****************************/
#iwatch
{
    position: absolute;

    top:-900px;
    left:0px;
    background-image: url('../images/New Folder/iWatch-4.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
    height: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 213px;
    padding-top: 127.79%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) */
                /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
    z-index: 1000;
    float:left;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #iwatch { height: auto;
    max-width:50%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #iwatch {height: auto;
    max-width:60%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    #iwatch { height: auto;
    max-width:100%; }
}
/****************pen*******************/
#pen
{
    position: absolute;

    top:-870px;
    left:-50px;  
    background-image: url('../images/New Folder/handle.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
    height: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 177px;
    padding-top: 84.79%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) */
                /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
    z-index: 1000;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #pen { height: auto;
    max-width:50%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #pen {height: auto;
    max-width:60%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    #pen { height: auto;
    max-width:100%; }
}
.row
{

    height: 33%;
}
```

Comment: what are your inputs? have you tried anything?

Comment: why don't you just make it one background image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition of the `.img-responsive` class. This applies `max-width: 100%;`, `height: auto;` and `display: block;` to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.

To center images which use the `.img-responsive` class, use `.center-block` instead of `.text-center`.

An alternate solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26573319/3711562)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5y62c4af/) of the alternate solution (jFiddle)

Comment: In your example, If I want one google image on left hand side and another one is on right hand side simultaneously in same row  such that it is responsive in every device. Then what should I do? As you can see in given image example of iphone and headphone images.

Comment: This was question I wanted to ask. So there no need to create separate question. Please edit the code in your answer.

Comment: Here new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807754/fix-position-of-images-at-left-center-and-right-on-page-but-also-responsive?noredirect=1#comment53452274_32807754

Comment: @AbhishekGupta posted answer