# Bootstrap: Different sized photos?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap 3, but have a problem with equal size on my images.
[1[https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6kQs.jpg][1]][1]

I use this

```
.col-lg-4 img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;          
    }
```

But see not looks beautiful !
[![https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmqlQ.jpg][1]][1]

My script is:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
            <h4>Опел Астра TBI</h4>
            <div class="text-left">
            <div>Произведена: Януари 1995 г</div>
            <div>Пробег: 200000 км.</div>
            <div>Двигател: Бензинов</div>
            <div>Цена: 20000 лв.</div>
            </div>
            <span><a href="#" class="label label-danger" rel="tooltip" title="Zoom">Детайли</a></span>

        </div>
        <img src="ful_upload/2005-lotus-elise-front-left.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
        <div style="background: silver;" class="hidden-xs visible-mb-block text-center">Опел Астра TBI<span class="text-right">8800 лв</span></div>
    </div>
```

How to do it to see coterminous show?

Comment: have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903183/how-to-create-a-responsive-image-in-twitter-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps also try to  add max-height to the custom css.

```
.col-lg-4 img{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 200px;          
}
```

Comment: Peter Scott your exemple script, not allowed my problem