# Get text to go below image responsive

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to get my media queries to work properly, but the `image` is displaying @ 100% of the screen (which I wanted), but the text on `.right` is still `float`ing from the `original` declaration (see the white "text" on the right of the image).

**Here's the `media queries css`**

```
@media screen 
  and (max-width: 480px){ 
    #header .header_adjust{
        width:98%;
    }

    #header .header_adjust .left {

        width:100%;
        height: auto;
        margin:0%;
        background-color:red;
    }
        #header .left img{
            margin:0%;
            width:100%;
            height:auto;

        }

    #header .header_adjust .right {
        float:none;
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        clear:both;
        margin:0%;
        background-color:black;
    }
  }
```

**original css:**

```
#header .header_adjust {
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
    }

    #header .left{
        width:17.95833335%;
        float:left;
/*      background-color: red;*/
    }
        #header .left img{
            margin:0%;
            max-width:100%;
            max-height:100%;
            -moz-border-radius:5px 20px 5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px 20px 5px; border-radius:5px 20px 5px;
        }
    #header .right{
        width:79.95833335%;
        max-height:100%;
        min-height:100%;
        margin:0% 1%;
        /*background-color: red;*/
        background:
            linear-gradient(27deg, #151515 5px, transparent 5px) 0 5px,
            linear-gradient(207deg, #151515 5px, transparent 5px) 10px 0px,
            linear-gradient(27deg, #222 5px, transparent 5px) 0px 10px,
            linear-gradient(207deg, #222 5px, transparent 5px) 10px 5px,
            linear-gradient(90deg, #1b1b1b 10px, transparent 10px),
            linear-gradient(#1d1d1d 25%, #1a1a1a 25%, #1a1a1a 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 75%, #242424 75%, #242424);
            background-color: #131313;
            background-size: 20px 20px;
        -moz-border-radius:5px;
        -webkit-border-radius:5px;
        border-radius:5px;
        -webkit-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
        flex: 1;
        float:right;
    }
```

**html:**

```
<div class="header_adjust">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='my_pic.jpg') }}" alt="My Pic" />
    </div><!--left-->
    <div class="right">
        <h2>
        Test test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Tes              
        </h2>
    </div><!--right-->
    <div id="clear"> </div>
</div><!--header_adjust-->
```

Comment: `width:98%` from header might be a clue. What are you expecting to see in both large and small screens?

Comment: On full display 1400 width and greater, .left and right are floated (currently working on "original css". However, on 480 width, they are still floating, and .right() is floating off the page at 480 width

Comment: Bootstrap CSS Images Reference  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903183/how-to-create-a-responsive-image-in-twitter-bootstrap-3

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp

Comment: @Cola - im not using bootstrap...

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin - #header .header_adjust{} is ultimately controlling it, but how can i adjust it to allow #header .header_adjust .left{} to take up a whole space, and #header .header_adjust .right{} to take up a whole space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `display: flex`, the child elements will be displayed side-by-side, even if they are not floated. See here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

You can probably fix your problem by including this directive:

`@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #header .header_adjust { display: block; }
}`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pbosakov/apfy0nLw/