# Best way to display a full screen img that is smaller than bigger size resolution screens such as an 27 inch iMac Retina resolution 5120 x 2880

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, responsive-images

I have a stock image of 1772 px. This image is the largest available. The raw file is gone so I can't create an image of 5120 px wide. How would the markup and CSS look for that image if I want to be able to stretch it nicely across the entire width of the iMac?

Minimum requirements:

- I'm using Bootstrap so it has to work with that. And preferably with the `img-responsive` built-in class. Do I need to have the `img`-tag in a `container-fluid` div?
- `<picture>`-element needs to be used since art directing is involved. When the viewport hits 767px and lower I'm displaying the image in portrait mode.

Here's the code I'm experimenting with:

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 768px)"
            srcset="/img/landscape/large.jpg 1772w,
                /img/landscape/medium.jpg 886w,
                /img/landscape/small.jpg 443w"
            sizes="100w" />

    <source srcset="/img/portrait/large.jpg 955w,
                /img/portrait/medium.jpg 640w,
                /img/portrait/small.jpg 320w"
            sizes="100vw" />

    <img src="/img/landscape/medium.jpg" alt="" />
</picture>
```

Currently firefox and Chrome managemes to strech out the image nicely but IE10 stops at 1772px and leaves white-space on the right of the image.

If I set the `img` to `width:100%` the image will stretch but I'm confused of wheather this is the right approach since in Bootstrap they use `max-width`.

Comment: You will need to use the `width` property. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18903687/1264804.