# Why is my responsive image not working?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm still learning CSS and can't figure out why I can't get this image to behave responsively in my template.

It was originally a background image that I decided to replace with a normal image and when maximized I wanted the text to be to the right of the image (without overlap) and when in responsive I wanted the Image to be above the text.

It seems to just overlap, can anyone tell what I've missed in my CSS?

```
<!-- IMAGE CONTAINER SECTION 1 -->
<section class="image-container-section-1 gry-bg">

    <!-- IMAGE CONTAINER  -->
    <div class="image-container-5"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT5MOpet1ps36ZgsQ98y7O8sJX4vIevqmvMJmr3F1zZRq9n_RYXaQ"/></div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">

                <!-- TEXT CONTAINER  -->
                <div class="image-container-1-text">
                    <h3 class=" slideInUp">Dummy Text</h3>
                    <p class="">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,</p>
                    <a class=" " href="">learn more</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6kyomgsv/3/

Comment: You don't show any CSS.

Comment: @Rob, he does in the fiddle.

Comment: @MadanBhandari, The OP's title is a little misleading. It seems that he's not asking a question so much about how to make the image itself responsive. But rather where to place the image within his markup so it's responsive. (2 column to a stacked layout)

Comment: @EnigmaRM Not good enough. Code and markup must be placed here. Third party sites can disappear tomorrow and be of no value to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking to have your content split into 2 columns. When on smaller devices, you want the columns to be stacked. It appears that you're trying to do that with Bootstrap. But that library has not been loaded in the Fiddle. I've updated the fiddle to include the necessary CSS (under external resources) https://jsfiddle.net/6kyomgsv/12/

Then we can use the built-in classes to get the desired layout. You already have the HTML in place to do it. And you can delete your image positioning CSS and move the image down a few lines.

```
<!-- IMAGE CONTAINER SECTION 1 -->
<section class="image-container-section-1 gry-bg">

  <!-- IMAGE CONTAINER  -->
  <div class="image-container-5"></div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT5MOpet1ps36ZgsQ98y7O8sJX4vIevqmvMJmr3F1zZRq9n_RYXaQ" class="img-responsive" /></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">

        <!-- TEXT CONTAINER  -->
        <div class="image-container-1-text">
          <h3 class=" slideInUp">Dummy Text</h3>
          <p class="">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries,</p>
          <a class=" " href="">learn more</a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- END IMAGE SECTION 1 -->
```

`.col-md-6` allows you to split the grid in half. In this case, `.col-md` will keep it that way until the width is below 970px, and then it will stack on top of each other. You can add additional bootstrap classes if you want additional layout options on smaller devices. Review the [Bootstrap Docs for a nice graph](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

I've also added the bootstrap class of `img-responsive` to your image. This allows the image itself to take the width of its container. If it's a larger image, I usually add that. But may opt not to if I don't want it to resize and have already planned for it to look well on mobile.

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you!!!! You have saved me about 5 extra hours! Your explanation was awesome too!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `img` width in percentage

OR

in bootstrap you can use

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

Read more [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903183/how-to-create-a-responsive-image-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)

One more thing : *You have not added bootstrap library in fiddle*.

***PS : Search question before asking on SO.***

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `float`. [Read about float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

You gave your image absolute positioning, which takes it OUT of the flow of elements, so it doesn't know to push the text either direction.

**CSS:**

```
.image-container-5 > img {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

And then in "responsive", you need to add a media query..

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .image-container-5 > img {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6kyomgsv/10/

Answer (score 0):

You are applying `position:absolute` to the image directly and not giving any width .

Example :

```
.image-container-5{
position:relative;
width: some percentage %

}
```

Fyi: You can apply whatever position property to container ei. Float,top,right ect...

Then :

```
 .image-container-5 img{
     width:100%:
     max-width:100%;
}
```

Fyi: If you desire to use `position:absolute` directly on image , then container must be `position:relative`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I changed some styling and added the jsfiddle below. I'm not sure if that helps entirely but you could always make it responsive with media queries. In order to float left, I removed the absolute position and made it float left.

```
.image-container-5 > img {
/*   position: absolute; */
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 20px; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fnez/8ruyaykh/1/