# Bootstrap - how to stop images overlapping on smaller window size?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have this:

```
<div id="members">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="members" class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h3>Text</h3>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
                <img src="images/1.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="images/1.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="images/1.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="images/1.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="images/1.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="images/1.png">
                </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However when I make the browser window narrower, they start to overlap. How can I control this? And how can I remove some of the images on the smaller browser window?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding `img-responsive` class to the <img > tags?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a responsive image that also scales up in Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903183/how-to-create-a-responsive-image-that-also-scales-up-in-bootstrap-3)

Comment: Which bootstrap are you using? I'm guessing bootstrap 3 by the classes you're using, if so, add class`img-responsive` to your images

Comment: I still have the overlap issue with img-responsive. Perhaps I need to change the column numbers?

Comment: You have columns inside of a column `<div id="members" class="col-md-12 text-center">..... <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">` This might be affecting it. Make sure the img's also don't have a min-height or width.

Comment: Can you provide a live demo with the issue (snippet, codepen, jsbin)?

Answer (score 6):

Bootstrap 4 uses an .img-fluid class for responsive images,
[from the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/)

```
<img src="images/1.png" class="img-fluid" />
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to add img-responsive class to the images, and hidden-xs to the container div (in case you want to hide in mobile). Hidden-sm for tablet, hidden-md for small desktop, and hidden-lg for large desktop:

```
<div class="col-md-2 hidden-xs">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/880000" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

Pen: https://codepen.io/giannidk/pen/rwpmpx?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this code in my browser and it seems fine. The divs aren't overlapping for me and are being displayed as a normal block element. If you want the images to readjust with the browser window try messing with the width and height settings. Setting them as percentages of the browser window. 
For the image divs, width: 15%, and give a 5% padding on the left and right sides of the row.

The images may be too large for them all to be displayed on the same line. Try resizing them in an editor.